# Design of Experiment for one factor in R

Tags: r, time-series, panel-data, experiment-design, blocking

Is there an package to design an experiment with a single factor, potentially with multiple levels?

I want to know how a certain voltage depends on temperature and for that I initially planned to measure the temperature from $5 ° C$ up to $80 ° C$ in $5 ° C$ steps. But simply ramping up the temperature feels wrong.
To be more precise, I want to evaluate the dependency of voltage on the temperature. The latter shall be randomized and replicated. On this occasion I'm wondering whether to consider blocking as well as the entire experiment will take about two weeks since the temperature differences are large and the system has to settle down each time.

Comment: There are quite a few packages, but none are going to help you unless you specify just what your problem is. If you can confidently assume a linear relation between voltage & temperature, you'll take an equal number of observations at the most extreme temperatures you can obtain.

Comment: If you had the opportunity to see my comment and answer for the more recent re-statement of this question, which has now been locked, they have some potential suggestions about this, but as already stated, there is not enough detail here to answer conclusively. I will attempt to improve this question by bringing over some of the changes in the duplicate, but it would still need more detail about the problem.

Comment: @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica I thought this was specific, at least I don't know what else to add? Actually, I'm expecting a negative quadratic behaviour which will be cut so it's going to look more like a logarithmic, or so. But I'm not so sure about that's why I wanna' perform this experiment..

Comment: @AndrewA Sorry, where do I see your comment? And which duplicate?

Comment: @Ben The comment was on the other version of this post that was called a duplicate of this one and which was closed for that reason,  [and is here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/578363/r-package-for-doe-with-a-single-factor). I might also bring my comment from there over here as well.

Comment: @Ben My old comment:  _What functionality above base R and it's most common basic packages are you looking for, specifically? Are there other experimental design packages that you have considered that do not work for you, and if so what differences would you prefer? More importantly, you have not given much detail on what it is you expect R to be doing for you. Is is just for analysis, or do you want it making the design as well etc. More details on what you are looking for would be helpful._  Also, I guess you could always try [looking here](https://cran.r-project.org/view=ExperimentalDesign)

Comment: Got it, there are probably "basic" packages and the like which are able to cover my needs but I don't know which. The source you linked to is quite overwhelming, tbh. This would take me weeks only to figure out which function to use out of which package..

Comment: @Ben the link was the best I could do unless you describe exactly what type of functionality you expect out of a prospective package.