# R package for DoE with a single factor?

Tags: r, experiment-design

Is there a package for R available to construct an experiment design with only a single factor?

To be more precise, I want to evaluate the dependency of voltage on the temperature. The latter shall be randomized and replicated.
On this occasion I'm wondering whether to consider blocking as well as the entire experiment will take about two weeks since the temperature differences are large and the system has to settle down each time.

Comment: What functionality above base `R` and it's most common basic packages are you looking for, specifically? Are there other experimental design packages that you have considered that do not work for you, and if so what differences would you prefer?  More importantly, you have not given much detail on what it is you expect R to be doing for you. Is is just for analysis, or do you want it making the design as well etc. More details on what you are looking for would be helpful.

Comment: I'm familiar with almost FrF2 but you can't construct designs with a single factor, there. I guess one does not necessarily have to but I'm not so deep into statistics to do that on my own in base R...  but I believe I can do the analysis on my own, so I'd need "only" the design but when there is a package available which does both I'd also be fine with that.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to answer you, though it is somewhat vague at this point what you are looking for.
It seems that you already have a setup to gather the data you want.
The basic way I would try to analyze the data you would have would generally be regressions (`lm` or `glm`, as appropriate) or `aov` analyses. In the simplest formulation, you would input the formula as `voltage ~ temperature` in input the appropriately labeled data.
As for blocking, which you specifically mentioned, I would handle that by adding other variables to your formula. It seems specifically that you are concerned about a time element as well. You could create an ordered categorical variable for when each measurement happened (or group them more), put the time elapsed in as a numeric variable, or use one of `R`'s built-in time-series-regression tools, such as `ts` and `arima`. `lubridate` might be a helpful package for some of this, but so would all of the `tidyverse`.
Some packages that would useful if you are looking into time series include `zoo`, *(maybe) `plm`*, `xts`, and `tsibble`, though depending on the specifics that you want, you might want to [look here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/TimeSeries.html).

Of course, you *did* ask for [specifically experimental design packages](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/ExperimentalDesign.html). Since I am still not sure what you are looking for those packages to do, I would recommend ones that would go relatively well with the approach I outlined above, which would be `MOTE` and its dependencies, and `GAD`. I could elaborate more with more detail.

Comment: Thank you, sorry for being so vague. I guess this is caused by my assumption that the term "design experiment" would be more specific. With that I'd expect a procedure/package which results in planning the experiment itself on how to run the experiment like which data points have to set to what in which order and so on.